# node.js log module bunyan change timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, timezone

I'm using this logging module bunyan.js which is included in the framwork restify.js. The module does outprint a time in the log file/console, however, I want to change the time to UTC/GMT, not sure if it's possible wihtout modifying the module code?

Comment: Did you get any answer for this post?

Comment: This is Isaac from Peru.
Try my solution in this link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66251303/15230538

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use local time anywhere else in your process, one way to achieve what you want is to change the timezone for the process. Either by writing this statement at the startup of you application:

```
process.env.TZ = 'UTC'
```

Or by starting it with a environment variable from the command line, like this:

```
TZ=UTC node main.js
```

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing the same issue and resolved it by adding a custom attribute, localtime, while creating the logger using bunyan.createLogger method like this:

```
var init = function () {
    log = bunyan.createLogger({
        name: 'myLogs',
        src: true,
        localtime: new Date().toString();
    });
};
```

By doing this, I get an extra field in my log called localtime with the appropriate time as per my timezone.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will only give you an extra `localtime` property with the time the server was started and will stay the same for as long as the server is running. It won't give you the correct time stamp on each request like the default `time` property on the Bunyan log.